# listview with button ItemCommand event not triggered

Tags: asp.net

Using a `ListView` control for the first time, I set a `CommandName` that will make the event.

`ListView_ItemCommand` should be triggered when I click on the button, but it's not. Nothing triggered when I clicked it.

```xml
<asp:ListView ID="ListView" runat="server" itemcommand="ListView_onItemCommand" 
            onitemcommand="ListView_ItemCommand">
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table runat="server" 
                    style="background-color: #FFFFFF;border-collapse: collapse;border-color: #999999;border-style:none;border-width:1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            No data was returned.</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="background-color:#DCDCDC;color: #000000;">
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="BirthdayLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Birthday") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="CourseNameLabel" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("CourseName") %>' />
                    </td>
                       
                    <td style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Edit" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/edit_icon.png" CommandName="Edit" OnClick="Edit_OnClick" />
                    </td>
                     <td style="text-align: center">
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="Delete" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/delete_icon.png" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="Delete" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>

protected void ListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "Delete")
        {
            Label1.Text = "Edit From Button";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your command name to something other than

```
 CommandName="Edit"
```

i.e.

```
CommandName="MyEdit"
```

Command="Edit" fires the `ListView_ItemEditing` command instead. I think this will mask the ItemCommand. But TBH when I've made this mistake it's crashed the page because of the missing event handler.

*So explanation 2*

The other explanation could be that you are rebinding the grid. This often causes events to seem to disappear. Check you're not doing this

Comment: Hello Mr Crab ,i do change the name og command to any other name but the result are the same :(,the event not triggered ,i set the debug point one the begin of event but it's not enter the event.what can i do?

Comment: @EHABTHD. Is the control rebinding perhaps?